# How exactly Radiocarbon dating Works?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, half-life

So how exactly does ***Carbon Dating*** work ?

$^{14}$C is produced from $^{14}$N in the atmosphere. Since there is considerable amount of **Nitrogen** in the atmosphere,we can have quantifiable amount of $^{14}$C in the atmosphere, the ratio of $^{14}$C to $^{12}$C is $1:10^{12}$.

An average human weights $80\,\rm kg$, $18\%$  of our body is *Carbon* ,that's $14.4\,\rm kg$ ,so every time we are breathing we have $6.194×10^{26}$ Carbon atoms with us and around
$7×10^{14}$ $^{14}$C atoms.

When the human body dies, the $^{14}$C atoms stop getting replenished and the number of atoms starts to get reduced.

So its rate of decay is $0.0001209424$ per year.

Now how do we proceed with finding the life time.

Scientists supposedly burn a piece of the adtifact to find the CO$_2$. I don't get this part .

Comment: You extract carbon from a sample, ionize it, accelerate it, magnetically separate it, and count the two masses to get a ratio. See for example https://www.pelletron.com/products/accelerator-mass-spectrometry-ams-systems/

Comment: Where does the information about burning the sample to obtain $CO2_$ come from?

Comment: @MisterMak https://www.nde-ed.org/Physics/X-Ray/carbon14dating.xhtml

Comment: @MisterMak - burning the material to form a gas leaves much of the non-carbon stuff as solids. Now one either feeds the ion source with the gas, or can readily remove the other main gas component, water.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating).

Answer (score 2):

> ...the $^{14}\text{C}$ atoms stop getting replenished and the number of atoms starts to get reduced...

It's not the number of $^{14}\text{C}$ atoms that matters, it's the *ratio* of $^{14}\text{C}$ to $^{12}\text{C}$. That ratio remains constant throughout the organism's life, but then it starts to change after the organism dies and stops exchanging carbon with its environment.

> Scientists supposedly burn a piece of the artifact to find the CO2. I don't get this part.

Presumably you are talking about an artifact that was made from plant or animal tissue (wood, leather, sinews, grass, etc.)

An archaeologist can analyze the $\text{CO}_2$ from the burning with a [*mass spectrometer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry) to measure the $^{14}\text{C}$ to $^{12}\text{C}$ ratio, and thereby determine approximately how long ago the wood or leather or whatever was harvested.

---

P.S., Depending on what equipment is available in the mass spec lab, it may be possible to liberate carbon from the sample by other means than burning.

Comment: Ok I understand that the ratio gets changed ,but how does this help with our cause ?My ratio was 1:$10^{12}$ at the beginning ,now it's changed ,I don't understand how this piece of info helps us

Comment: @HarryCase, Maybe I did not understand what you are asking. Are you asking for the exact mathematical formula that maps the isotope ratio to a number of years? I don't know that off the top of my head. With a bit of work, I could derive a naive version from the ratio in air and from the half-life of $^{14}\text{C}$, which I would look up using Google. But, it turns out, the naive version can be pretty far from the mark. There apparently are multiple reasons why. You can read [the Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating) to get a sense of it.

Comment: yeah I was asking how the mass ratio helps us with finding the age of the artifact